# OpenSSL's version on centos 7.2

Tags: linux, centos, openssl

I am using centos 7.2,
the version that comes with centos 7.2 is 1.0.1 ,
I intalled 1.0.2 form source,
then view the version,but it's  still 1.0.1 .

What should I do if I want to use 1.0.2?

```
[root@i001 ~]# openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
built on: Tue Mar  1 15:07:53 UTC 2016
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) md2(int) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: gcc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DKRB5_MIT -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -Wall -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -Wa,--noexecstack -DPURIFY -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/pki/tls"
engines:  dynamic
```

Comment: try this https://syslint.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-upgrade-openssl-on-centos-7-or-rhel-7/

Comment: Why do you need 1.0.2 ?  The package's changelog will show all the updates it receives, including back ported security updates.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not changed any options, your new binary is in /usr/local/bin now.

You can rebuild openssl from source rpm taken from Fedora project:

- Download https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/23/SRPMS/o/openssl-1.0.2h-1.fc23.src.rpm
- install rpm-build using yum
- rpm -ivh openssl-1.0.2h-1.fc23.src.rpm
- rpmbuild -bb ~/SPECS/openssl.spec

Install resulted RPM from ~/RPMS. Please be careful and first try with a virtual machine.